# Xenogears Pearfect works p.8 chronological year 4767

Tags: translation

"ゾハルがデウスの主動力炉"

As far as I understand, it says something like "*(A) Zohar is the power source of Deus' leadership.*", but "力炉" cannot be found in a dictionary.

Now 炉 has only one reading: ろ. But 力 can be read as ちから as well as りょく or りき. How is 力炉 to be read beside its meaning?

ゾハル - name of a monolithic object supposed to be the source of all of life and existence.

デウス - name of an AI taking control of the ゾハル for its purposes.

Comment: Why don't you search for 動力炉?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

主動力炉 is しゅどうりょくろ, "main power source".

- 主【しゅ】: (prefix) main
- 動力炉【どうりょくろ】: power generator, power source

  - 動力【どうりょく】: driving power, driving force
  - 炉【ろ】: furnace, reactor, generator

Perhaps you mistook it as 主導【しゅどう】 ("leadership"). The second kanji is different. 導 is "lead; guide", 動 is "move; drive".